# Not able to get excel sheet using UDF with Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, user-defined-functions

I am new in UDF(User defined function) with hybrid framework. I have created the "ExcelUtils" class. In which I have written the code for read and write the excel sheet. Also, I have created the "Utils" class, in this after capturing the testcase name from excel I have created one function name **getRowContains** in these I am not able to get object **excelSheet**.

**Utils class:**

```
public class Utils {

    private static FirefoxDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver openBrowser(int iTestCaseRow){
        String sBrowserName;
        try{
            sBrowserName= ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestCaseRow, Constant.Col_Browser);

            if(sBrowserName.equals("Mozilla")){
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/ileadsynapse/Desktop/CT/geckodriver");
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
                Log.info("New driver instantiated");
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Log.info("Implicit wait applied on the driver for 10 seconds");
                driver.get(Constant.URL);
                Log.info("Web application get launched");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.error("Class Utils | Method OpenBrowser | Exception Desc:"+e.getMessage());
        }

        return driver;

    }

    public static String getTestCaseName(String sTestCase){
        String value= sTestCase;

        try {
            int posi= value.indexOf("@");
            value = value.substring(0, posi);
            posi= value.lastIndexOf(".");
            value= value.substring(posi+1);

            return value;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
             Log.error("Class Utils | Method getTestCaseName | Exception desc : "+e.getMessage());
             throw(e);
        }

    }

    public static int getRowContains(String sTestCaseName, int colNum){
                int i;      
        try{
            int rowCount= excelSheet.


        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

}
```

**ExcelUtils:**

```
public class ExcelUtils {

    private static XSSFWorkbook excelBook;
    private static XSSFSheet excelSheet;
    private static XSSFCell cell;
    private static XSSFRow row;

    //This method is to set the File path and to open the Excel file, Pass Excel Path and Sheetname as Arguments to this method
    public static void setExcelFile(String Path, String SheetName) throws Exception{
        try{
            //Open excel file
            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
            // Access the required test data sheet
            excelBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            excelSheet = excelBook.getSheet("Sheet1");
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw(e);
        }
    }

    //This method is to read the test data from the Excel cell, in this we are passing parameters as Row num and Col num
    public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum){
        try {
            cell = excelSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
            String cellData = cell.getStringCellValue();
            return cellData;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    //This method is to write in the Excel cell, Row num and Col num are the parameters
    public static void setCellData(String Result, int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception{
        try{
            row = excelSheet.getRow(RowNum);
            cell = row.getCell(ColNum, row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if(cell==null){
                cell = row.createCell(ColNum);
                cell.setCellValue(Result);
            }else{
                cell.setCellValue(Result);
            }

            // Constant variables Test Data path and Test Data file name
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Constant.Path_TestData+ Constant.File_TestData);
            excelBook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            throw(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Can any one please help to resolving it. I have referred this tutorial: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/user-defined-functions/

Comment: Did you get any error ? if yes please post that and what do you want exactly ? do you want to read and write using excel ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created excel object to access the excelsheet in Utils class.

declare `private static XSSFSheet excelSheet;` in utils class to get excelsheet object.

or

create `ExcelUtils` object in utils class to access all the elements of ExcelUtils

Comment: As I have set the excel path in "ExcelUtils" class, then why need to define it in utils class?

Comment: edited my answer , hope you will get an idea to resolve your issue